# Body property ignored when generating json using Moshi

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

I have a simple class

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Person(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int
) {
    val country: String = "None"
}
```

but when converting to json, Moshi skips `country` property.

How to include it in the resulting json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, it's not possible.

More info and explanation [here](https://github.com/square/moshi#default-values--constructors).